# jQuery - Iterating over field elements with maxlength

Tags: jquery

I have **several** form elements on a page with an attribute of maxlength and want to have a character countdown to alert the user of characters remaining. I thought this would work but each counter span is empty.

Here is a sample of the elements (all the rest are similar in structure):

```
<label for="homeTagline">Tagline</label>
<input type="text" name="homeTagline" value="IT'S YOUR LIFE!" maxlength="24" class="maxed" />
<br>
<span class='emphasisTxt'><span class='cntr'></span> characters of 24 remaining</span>
```

and here is my jquery

```
$('.maxed').each( function(){
   var ml = parseInt( $(this).attr('maxlength') );
   if( $(this).val().length() == 0){
      $(this).sibling('span.cntr').html(ml);
   } else {
      $(this).sibling('span.cntr').html(ml - $(this).val().length() );
   } // end if
});
```

Comment: Is "sibling" instead of "siblings" a typo?

Comment: You are going to need a listener to update the counter when the user types. Maybey listen for the "keyup" or "keypress" events.

Comment: both instances of this: $(this).val().length() should not have () on the end of length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking to accomplish?

```
$('.maxed').each(function(){
   var ml     = parseInt( $(this).attr('maxlength') );
   var length = $(this).val().length;

   $(this).nextAll('span:first').find('.cntr').html(ml-length);      
}).keyup(function() {
    var ml     = parseInt( $(this).attr('maxlength') );
    var length = $(this).val().length;

    $(this).nextAll('span:first').find('.cntr').html(ml - length );
});
```

Here's an **updated** jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/RtHyX/4/

Comment: This is perfect for the count remaining except that it doesn't set the initial value of the counter spans on page load. I would try to mashup from some of the excellent answers above but your code is so condensed, I wanted to see your way of getting the initial values

Comment: Just add this to @sbeliv01's answer to set the initial values: `$('span.cntr').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).parent().prevAll('.maxed').attr('maxlength') - $(this).parent().prevAll('.maxed').val().length);
});​` jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RtHyX/3/

Answer (score 3):

I see three problems:

1. `.length()` on `$(this).val().length()` is supposed to be `.length`. It's a property of `String`, not a method.
2. jQuery has no `.sibling` method, it's `.siblings`, in plural.
3. `span.cntr` is not a sibling of the field, it's actually a child of a slibling. So you need something like `$(this).siblings('.emphasisTxt').find('span.cntr')` to select it.

See a [working version on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XBrFZ/3/).

Also, do you want the span to be updated when the field is edited (not just on page load)? You'd need to setup a  keyup listener for that. Please clarify.

Comment: The `.length` check isn't really needed. `24-0` is 24.

Comment: @Rocket, `.length` will never be zero in the `else` :P

Comment: @XyanEwing: I meant, remove the `if/else` altogether, it's useless.

Comment: if the form is an insert instead of an update, the value would be null and max chars would be left

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the `siblings()`-Bit. (which you misspelled, probably).

`siblings()` selects only those elements, that are... well... siblings. 
Siblings of your input field are your `label`, `<br>` and `<span class="emphasisTxt">`. As `span.cntr` is *inside* the latter one, it is no longer a sibling of `this`.

Instead, `$(this).siblings('span.emphasisTxt').children('span.cntr')` should do the magic.

Comment: Additionally, as others have said, if you want the field to update automatically, you'll need a keyup listener to trigger your function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your initial problems: http://jsfiddle.net/kPYqq/ What you were looking for was not a sibling, it was a child of a sibling. Length is a property of a string and not a function so remove the ()'s.

I know this doesn't directly answer your issue but it might be a useful alternative. I have used this jquery plugin before on a site that does similar to what you are looking to do:
http://nooshu.com/jquery-plug-in-characters-left